# require('express')().get('/test', ), it is a route with missing callback or it is a get method returns value of '/test' app setting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Sorry, I am new to express. I have following doubt.

Suppose, I missed specifying callback with express().get('/v1/message-get',) method, then it is treated as normal get method (Returns the value of '/v1/message-get' app setting)

or It should be a route path (Routes HTTP GET requests to the specified path '/v1/message-get')?

For example,

**********test.js********************

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// in this case, I did not provide callback 
// function after comma (assume, I missed it somehow) 
app.get('/v1/message-get',); 

// this one having a callback
app.get('/v2/message', function(req, res){
 console.log('Call back present');
});

module.exports = app;
```

---

'/v2/message' is a valid route but, what about '/v1/message-get'.
I know, it is not valid route (as callback function is not provided), but I am not getting any console error on starting node server.
is it because app.get('/v1/message-get',) treated as getting app setting for value '/v1/message-get'

Ref: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.get

Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not clear question.

Comment: @Tyler2P
I believe now question will be clear.